# Have cookstyle only check for errors that would cause cookbook execution to fail

Tags: chef-infra, rubocop

I want to use cookstyle in a cicd pipeline. I currently am not linting at all though. right now I just want to catch syntax error that would actually cause the cookbook to fail execution

Can I have cookstyle only check for actual errors and not just style conventions?

Comment: There is a `knife cookbook test` option to [check cookbook](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_cookbook/#test) for syntax errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a very rudimentary [check for syntax](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_cookbook/#test), you could use the `knife cookbook test` sub-command to make sure the cookbook execution won't fail.

However, as we get deeper into the Chef eco-system it is worth slowly introducing `rubocop`/`cookstyle` rules as @DracoAter suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should eventually enable most of the cookstyle linting rules. If enabling them right away creates an overwhelming amount of offenses, you can create an automatic configuration: a .rubocop_todo.yml file.

Yes. Cookstyle is based on rubocop, so actually in this case rubocop documentation suits.

https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html#automatically-generated-configuration

It will disable the failing cops, and then you can enable them 1 by 1 and fix in small portions.

Run:

```sh
cookstyle --auto-gen-config
```

to generate the file.